# Laravel 5.5 get multiple records which are recently updated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am displaying multiple records which changed recently. In previous view there is a button that when I click, all records' kitchen_status becomes 1 from 0. After that if I add more records and change its kitchen_status to 1, then I only want to display latest records which has kitchen_status as 1. Here is what I had tried to get:

```
    $orders = Order::where([
    'kitchen_status' => 1,
    'delivery_status' => 0,
])
    ->where('updated_at', \DB::raw("(select max(`updated_at`) from orders)"))
    ->get();
```

This works good, but when I add new record that kitchen_status with default value of 0, then none records display. I know that last ->where() is wrong but how can I make it right?

In short, I want to display all records with latest updated_at. Some little help will save my day.

Comment: add the code how you tried

Comment: I don't want to limit with time or nos. I want to display all records which has same and latest 'updated_at' column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried this code and it works perfect but still I am looking short and pure method. Here is code that I found:

```
$orders = Order::select('orders.*')
->where('kitchen_status', 1)
->where('delivery_status', 0)
->where('updated_at', \DB::raw("(SELECT max(updated_at) FROM orders WHERE kitchen_status = 1 AND delivery_status = 0)"))
->get();
```

Is it good to check this answer as right answer or please add more answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can help.

```
$orders = Order::where([
'kitchen_status' => 1,
'delivery_status' => 0,])->orderBy('update_at','DESC')->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question 100% But I think what you are looking for is

```
Model::whereDate('updated_at', '>', \Carbon::now()->subHours(2));
```

Which will give you all the records where `updated_at` is older than 2 hours. The parameter can be changed to something else like 10 for hours etc, there is also a `subDays(), subMonths()` etc, if you need a bigger range.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of the most recent entries you want as

```
$orders = Order::where([
    'kitchen_status' => 1,
    'delivery_status' => 0,
])->orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->limit(20)
    ->get();
```

You can change the number to what you want.